# How to setup a HTTP/s Proxy behind Squid/Sockd Proxy

Tags: unix, proxy, solaris, squid

I'm looking for an (easy) way to have a http/s proxy server configured to proxy all traffic directed at the internet (speak not at a host in our subnet) to another proxy server.

**A short explanation of our setup:**

In our lab network all hosts use a proxy server (Squid) for any internet access, now there is an additional network within our lab environment that is almost totally isolated but we would like to allow it's hosts http/s (and maybe ftp) access to the internet. It is a requirement that this access is also done via a proxy server.

I can't give this second proxy direct internet access so the traffic will have to be redirected via the existing proxy server. I do have full control over both servers though and some liberty to make changes.

Any ideas on if or how this is feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple to set Apache up as a dedicated proxy server.

1. Ensure `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` are installed.
2. Strip all the non-essentials from httpd.conf (security is always a good thing)
3. Ensure your lab clients have their DNS requests forwarded to the Squid. You may need http://sourceforge.net/projects/proxychains
4. Configure your Apache as a forward proxy, you will have to read the manuals I'm afraid as every installation will have it's wrinkles (ssl, caching etc)

Comment: I'm gonna give it Apache a try, didn't think of it when trying to find a proxy software which is capable of doing what I want here. DNS is not an issue, as all request are handled by DNS servers in the encapsulated network, but thx for the hint anyway.